# Postgres Table experiencing AccessShareLock which reduce the throughput of the system

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, pgbouncer

I have a Postgres Function which performs select query on a table to perform an arithmetic operation and calculate the result. I have setup pgbouncer before the postgresql server for better throughput. The System configurations are as follows.

```
NGINX -> PHP-FPM -> Laravel 8 -> PgBouncer -> PostgreSQL 12
```

**System Configuration**

```
AWS M6G.8X Large - 32 CPU and 128 GB RAM
```

**PgBouncer**

```
pool_mode = transaction
max_client_conn = 5000
default_pool_size = 450
min_pool_size=400
server_lifetime = 300
server_idle_timeout = 2
server_connect_timeout = 10
server_login_retry = 1
```

**PostgreSQL**

```
max_connections = 500
shared_buffers = 14080MB
effective_cache_size = 42240MB
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 7208kB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 4GB
max_worker_processes = 20
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4
max_parallel_workers = 20
max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 4
```

Even with this configuration, I could experience a very less throughput(**Average time and Maximum response time are larger than 2 sec eventhough the single transaction produce the result within 300 ms**) when executed 200 parallel requests for a total of 5000 requests.

[image]

I see the table used in the Postgres function is experiencing **AccessShareLock** by which the postgres function is waiting for more time to return the result. Is there any way to improve the throughput for my system by reducing the AccessshareLock or by increasing any system configuration?

[image]

**Note:**

I increased the postgres max_connections to 1000 and pgbouncer default pool size to 900 which doesn;t show any improvements.

Comment: max_connections = 1000 will most likely make things slower, not faster (unless your server has hundreds of CPUs and many hard disks)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ... My aim is to achieve atleast 400 requests/sec with the current system configuration. What configurations should I change to achieve that considering the single request take around 300-400 ms response time?

Comment: What makes you think  AccessShareLock has anything to do with this?  It doesn't show up in any of the data you show.